# Parse varchar of list of dict to array of row in presto db

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I am trying to convert a varchar to array of rows where my column looks like this: [image]

I have tried

```
select  cast(json_parse(sponsored_bids_filtered) as array(row (bid varchar, day date, eventtime timestamp)))
```

but I keep getting the error:

> INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast JSON to array(row(bid varchar, day date, eventtime timestamp))

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use regex to solve this:

```
    transform(
  zip(
    regexp_extract_all(
      sponsored_bids_filtered, 'bid=(\d+\.?\d+),',
      1
    ),
    regexp_extract_all(
      sponsored_bids_filtered, 'day=(.*?),',
      1
    ),
    regexp_extract_all(
      sponsored_bids_filtered, 'eventtime=(.*?)}',
      1
    )
  ),
  x -> cast(
    x as ROW(
      bid varchar, day date, eventtime timestamp
    )
  )
) as sponsored_bids_filtered
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html):

> Casting to BOOLEAN, TINYINT, SMALLINT, INTEGER, BIGINT, REAL, DOUBLE or VARCHAR is supported.

Presto does not handle date/timestamp conversions automatically when processing json, you can try using extra cast:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (json_str) AS (
    VALUES ('[
   {
      "bid":60.0,
      "day":"2022-06-12",
      "eventtime":"2022-06-12 09:45:59.403"
   }
]')
)

-- query
select transform(
        cast(json_parse(json_str) as array(ROW(bid varchar, day varchar, eventtime varchar))),
        r->cast(r as ROW(bid varchar, day date, eventtime timestamp))
    )
from dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| [{bid=60.0, day=2022-06-12, eventtime=2022-06-12 09:45:59.403}] |

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer! but in my data, there is no ":" for dictionary, its "=" . also, there are no explicit quotes around my key values - so still getting the same error

Comment: @blutab then your data is not an json and could not be parsed as something else than json string (so no meaningful parsing). How do you get this data, cause based on output it seems to already be an `row(...)`?